# Is there a novel or book expanding upon the first Deus Ex PC game? Or is there a basis in literature for the game?

Tags: deus-ex

I'm looking for books about Deus Ex 1, novels that deal with the contents of that game or even artbooks or similiar additional information on it. I'm aware that the newer games of that franchise have some literature on them, but I am not interested in the newer entries of the franchise.

Comment: http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Deus_Ex_publications

Comment: List/recommendation and shopping questions are off-topic. This also smacks of a lack of research (since I was able to find a list off of google with practically no effort).

Comment: None of those books are about the first game, I found the same list.

Comment: Regardless, questions about the availability of desired works is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing there is to an explanation of the world of the first game is *[The Deus Ex Continuity Bible](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_Bible)*.

> The Deus Ex Bible contains background information about the Deus Ex universe and a lot of information about this (like the date of birth of Paul Denton or the situation of "mech-augs" in 2052).
>
> The Deus Ex Bible is intended to summarize the universe details behind the Deus Ex universe with a few additions and modifications for the sake of maintaining consistency with the finished game and the current Deus Ex universe.
>
> Although some things didn't appear in Deus Ex (many missions in Texas, moon base etc.) and shouldn't be considered canon, the Bible looks closely at the details and background behind the events that appeared in the finished game.

Comment: Thanks, that's a fascinating read.

Comment: @JosephDoob: Yeah. I think I first found reference to the content that got cut in an exploration of the unused resources (https://tcrf.net/Deus_Ex). Some of the material is still present on the disc.